# Как обратиться к конкретным элементам списка?

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять, как сделать исключение для `empty`, использовать nth-child(even)?

В списке c классом elements, все li, кроме того что с
классом empty должны иметь цвет "yellowgreen". А те, у
которых есть аттрибут hasDropdown должны иметь отступ слева
30px

Правильно понимаю, как для hasDropdown должно быть ?

```css
.elements li:first-child {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.elements li:last-child {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="elements">
  <li class="item" hasDropdown>1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item empty">N/A</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item" hasDropdown>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.elements li[hasDropdown] {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.elements li:not(.empty){
color:yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<ul class="elements">
  <li class="item" hasDropdown>1</li>
  <li class="item">2</li>
  <li class="item empty">N/A</li>
  <li class="item">3</li>
  <li class="item" hasDropdown>4</li>
</ul>
```

Как то так. Хотя атрибут `hasDropdown` не валиден